# Abstracting a dbContext into a separate class - Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, interface, entity-framework-6, abstraction

I want to be able to abstract my EF6 context so that it is created once and used by multiple classes.  The code as follows:

Interface:

```
public interface IInterface<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> ExecStoredProc(string x, DateTime date,
             int y, string  statistics );
}
```

Context class:

```
public class Context
{
    public readonly StatisticsEntities StatContext;

    public static StatisticsRepo(StatisticsEntities statContext)
    {
        StatContext = statContext;
        return StatContext;
    }
}
```

Class that calls Context class:

```
public class Class2: Iinterface<Class2Type>
{
    var returnContext = context.StatisticsEntities();

    public IEnumerable<Class2Type> ExecStoredProc(string x, DateTime date,
            int y, string  statistics )
           {
              return returnContext.ExecMethod_Select(x,date,y,statistics).AsEnumerable();
           }

}
```

The following are my questions:

1. Is abstracting the context possible and if so is it a good practice to do.  My biggest concern is disposal.
2. Normally, StatContext would be a private variable, but I can't return that.  How can I keep StatContext private?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a different approach  and used property injection:

```
public class Context
    {
        //Property Injection to be used for all repo classes
        private StatisticsEntities _statContext = new StatisticsEntities();
        public StatisticsEntities StatContext { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I added a try catch finally block in the calling class to dispose of the context.